# Elastic Search 6.2.2 and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

From this [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch), it says that Spring Data Elastic Search 3.1.X supports Elastic Search 6.2.2. Will this also work with Spring Data Rest and Spring Boot? If yes, what dependencies do I need in my gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you Spring Data elastic search 3.1.x supports ES 6.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.4.0.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Kay-SR8'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.8.RELEASE'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release'
    }
}
```